# What's the good adjective for the causing configuration set of a bug?

Tags: single-word-requests, software

We have configuration options in a software source code, and certain (not all, but quite a lot) subsets of these options make valid configuration settings.
However, there are bugs that only live under some of these valid settings.
I would like to use an adjective for the configuration set (e.g. valid setting) with a structure like this:

> The ____ config set.

This should mean: the bug is present, if this config set is used.
What adjective could be used that could express that the bug is present when any of those configs are used?

Edit: it would be great if the technical term for it could be found.

Comment: It's a *configuration-dependent bug*. Such bugs that persist for long enough are sometimes known as *features*. "Hardware eventually fails. Software eventually works." -- Michael Hartung

Comment: But I'm looking for an adjective for the config set, not the bug :)

Comment: I doubt there is an official term. I guess you need a word like *culpable* or *applicable*?

Comment: "Bad" would be a good term and how about the form "Bugname", substituting whatever you call that bug? If there's only one bug it could be just "The Bug config set", else "The Bugname config set".

If the particular case supports it, might be "The Bug-bringer/maker/causing set"

Comment: I want to use it not for a certain bug but generally for any bug config sets :)

Comment: I'd call it the *host set*. Critter bugs have hosts, ie. the plants they are dependent on.

Comment: The bug is in the code all the time, it's just that the part(s) of the code containing the bug are only activated under certain conditions. As this is the case you could refer to the config set as the **bug activating** config set. (Or more likely the **{expletive} bug-activating set**).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One might refer to those configurations as "**bug-exposing**" or "**error-exposing**" or simply "**exposing**".  To expose is defined by [oxforddictionaries.com](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/expose) as

> Make (something) visible by uncovering it

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like ***buggy*** configuration - a configuration which is impacted by (or, like in this context, uncovers) a bug.

ODO:

> **[buggy](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/buggy)**
>   *ADJECTIVE*
>
> **2** (of a computer program or system) faulty in operation.
>
> ‘I had a system crash thanks to a usually-reliable program that issued
>   a buggy upgrade.’
>
> ‘In the past, typical translations from proprietary houses have had
>   buggy character sets and ended up with a weird mix of English and
>   whichever language.’

Comment: buggy config sounds like it refers to the bugginess of the config, whereas it would be much rather something else in the code that might malfunction or miss when the config is set that way. Like a wrong module of a certain kind gets in. But you might be right. I'll think it through :)